# Error while running zookeeper under supervison

Tags: apache-zookeeper, supervisord

I am trying to run zookeeper under supervison using **supervisor**.This is command i am using.

```
[program:zookeeper]
command=/usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
startetries=999
stopsignal=KILL
stopasgroup=true
log_stdout=true
log_stderr=true
logfile=/var/log/zookeeper/zookeeper.out
logfile_maxbytes=20MB
logfile_backups=10
```

**Error :**

```
zookeeper          FATAL      Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

**logs:**

```
2015-11-09 12:28:35,326 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 6769
2015-11-09 12:28:35,344 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 1; not expected)
2015-11-09 12:28:36,347 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 6778
2015-11-09 12:28:36,364 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 1; not expected)
2015-11-09 12:28:38,368 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 6791
2015-11-09 12:28:38,385 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 1; not expected)
2015-11-09 12:28:41,390 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 6797
2015-11-09 12:28:41,407 INFO exited: zookeeper (exit status 1; not expected)
2015-11-09 12:28:42,408 INFO gave up: zookeeper entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run the command manually, does it work?
`/usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground`

My suggestion would be to try to run it manually, than do a:
`ps -ef | grep zookeeper` to find the actual `java -cp ...` command.
Use that java command to start ZK as part of supervisor `command=*` config. This way, you will know if it is an issue with `zkServer.sh` and something missing (since it looks for other files like `zkEnv.sh`).

Comment: Using java -cp certainly works.Thanks man !!